# In The Back Of His/The Head

Tags: word-choice, determiners

Suppose a bullet struck the back side of someone's head:

1. He was shot in the back of ***his*** head.
2. He was shot in the back of ***the*** head.

Is one of them wrong?  Are they different?

Comment: Though **both convey the message,** I incline to use the first sentence. The possessive male pronoun fits better I guess. However **the** back of **the head** immediately after introducing *He* also seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the exact same thing, and neither is wrong. In English most of the time we use possessive determiners: these are words like 'his', 'my', or 'her'. However, sometimes we can use the definite article ('the') instead, usually when discussing parts of the body.

In some cases, the definite article is more natural. For example

> The ball hit me in the knee.

sounds more natural (at least in British English) than

> The ball hit me in my knee.

In other cases, 'the' sounds totally unnatural. *I hurt the knee* sounds incorrect; you should use

> I hurt my knee.

In some cases, such as those in your question, either can be used and they both sound natural. Any differences between the two sentences you gave are very subtle and likely to be highly subjective.

[Here is an article with more examples and discussion of this](https://sites.google.com/site/agrammaroferrors/1-1-the-noun-phrase/1-6/1-6-1).

Comment: Aw! **A** grammar of errors? Article with *grammar?* And also, is it the errors of grammar? Am I missing something? Or should we still read further after that sentence from an authentic document? :P

Comment: @MaulikV :p I'm sure the author is referencing [The Comedy of Errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Comedy_of_Errors), and is using the 6th or 7th definition of *grammar* as given [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grammar#Noun): **6. The basic rules or principles of a field of knowledge or a particular skill.** / **7. (UK, archaic) A textbook.**. (So it is a 'textbook'-like website describing errors people make with grammar!)